# How to simplify user input

Tags: java, exception, input, duplicates

How can I simplify this code?
I check every input for an error, but in the way that I do, the code is duplicated.

```
long houseNumberOfFloors;
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Enter valid house number of floors: ");
  try {
    houseNumberOfFloors = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    continue;
  }
  if (FlatAttrValidator.checkHouseNumberOfFloors(houseNumberOfFloors)) {
    break;
  }
}

Integer houseNumberOfLifts;
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Enter valid house number of lifts: ");
  try {
    houseNumberOfLifts = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    continue;
  }
  if (FlatAttrValidator.checkHouseNumberOfLifts(houseNumberOfLifts)) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Modularize. The duplicate code goes in a method. The method accepts the user prompt and returns the user input.

Comment: different types

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass conversion and validation as function(s).

```
private <T> T ask(BufferedReader br, String question, Function<String, T> converter) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(converter);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(question);
        String answer = br.readLine();
        try {
            T result = converter.apply(answer);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }
    }
}

int houseNumberOfLifts = (Integer) ask(br, "Enter valid house number of lifts: ",
    answer -> {
        int lifts = Integer.parseInt(answer);
        return FlatAttrValidator.checkHouseNumberOfLifts(lifts) ? lifts : null;
});
```

Here `answer ->` declares a parameter `answer`

Comment: I was just writing the same thing but with a custom `CheckedFunction<String, T, Ex extends Exception>` instead, so I'll stop :).  I think this version loops forever if `converter == null` though.

Comment: @BeUndead thanks very nice remark, added a `requireNonNull`. A pity, I would have liked to see a better answer with CheckedFunction.

Comment: It wouldn’t have been better. The examples they use throwing RuntimeExceptions, combined with not being able to catch parameterized types made it a messier version of this.

Answer (score 2):

I created the following solution for you, using functional interfaces:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class IReader {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);    

      Integer houseNumberOfFloors = getNumber(br, "Enter valid house number of floors: ", (i) -> FlatAttrValidator.checkHouseNumberOfFloors(i));
      Integer houseNumberOfLifts = getNumber(br, "Enter valid house number of lifts: ", (i) -> FlatAttrValidator.checkHouseNumberOfLifts(i));
      System.out.println("" + houseNumberOfFloors +"-" +houseNumberOfLifts);
    }

    public interface Checker {
        boolean check(Integer i);
    }

    private static Integer getNumber(BufferedReader br, String query, Checker checker) {

        Integer number;
        while (true) {
          System.out.println(query);
          try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
          } catch (NumberFormatException|IOException e) {
            continue;
          }
          if (checker.check(number)) {
            break;
          }
        }
        return number;
    }

    private static class FlatAttrValidator {
        static boolean checkHouseNumberOfFloors(Integer i) {
            return i>0;
        }
        static boolean checkHouseNumberOfLifts(Integer i) {
            return i>0;
        }
    }
}
```

It runs on https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/.